# Rendering fluid simulation and assigning material to water

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation

I am working on some fluid simulations in Blender, however this tool is completely new to me and I am having some issues in rendering the output to have a realistic aspect.

I have built a water basin, with a water piston which pushes the water and makes it flow on a geometry located on the opposite side of the basin.

My interest is to see the interaction of water waves with the texture of the geometry.

Therefore I need the output to be neat and with a very good resolution.
Here below some of the issues I am recreating:

1. I tried to set up the water material in both Cycles Render and
   Blender Render, however when I set it up in Cycles render the water
   area disappears when rendering the simulation in Blender Render. I want the water to appear
   transparent and with a realistic aspect. Which settings will give me
   the desired effect?
2. I would like the fluid to behave like water when it flows down
   through the texture. However it looks too viscous. The liquid
   viscosity was set, as instructed in the forum, to water however the
   final result looks more viscous. What can be the reason for this?
3. After the water flows down the surface, some water drops stay
   attached to the surface. Their shape is weird, not round as it
   should, but sharp. See here zoomed in picture:
   [image]
4. I would like the lighting of the simulation to be atmospheric (neat
   but not too strong), how can I get this result? I saw some tutorials
   but none of them helped me getting the result I desire.

Here is the link to the Blender file I am working on right now (https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mhe9dntwrmzvss/Doc.%20Forum.blend?dl=0).

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Welcome - it is better to ask one question at a time, the material and lighting is a different issue than improving the fluid sim. Try increasing the real world size - under the domains [fluid world settings](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/fluid/types/domain.html#domain-world).